# Many To Many обновление записи TypeORM

Tags: база-данных, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

Есть отношение Many-To-Many в NestJS приложении.
Посетители могут иметь несколько типов, а типы могут иметь несколько посетителей.

Вот что имеется на данный момент, но я не знаю, можно ли избежать visitorService в данном случае. Возможно ли такое? Т.е я хочу сделать добавление, без инъекции сервиса посетителей

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(VisitorTypeEntity)
    private visitorTypeRepository: Repository<VisitorTypeEntity>,
    private visitorService: VisitorService,
  ) {}


  async addVisitor(id: number, visitorId) {
    const type = await this.visitorTypeRepository.findOne(
      { id },
      { relations: ['visitors'] },
    );
    const visitor = await this.visitorService.getById(visitorId);
    type.visitors = [...type.visitors, visitor];
    return await this.visitorTypeRepository.save(type);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async addOrRemoveVisitor(id: number, visitorId, remove = false) {
    remove
      ? await this.visitorTypeRepository
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .relation(VisitorTypeEntity, 'visitors')
          .of(visitorId)
          .remove(id)
      : await this.visitorTypeRepository
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .relation(VisitorTypeEntity, 'visitors')
          .of(visitorId)
          .add(id);

    return { updated: true };
  }
```